# consultas complejas - error de sintaxis en agrupacion

Tags: mysql-workbench

se me pide una consulta en la que debo mostrar los medicos asignados a una zona y en el segundo parametro que esta en otra tabla cuantos medicos hay en dicha zona, la verdad que llevo un cacau de ordenes
He generado este select

```
SELECT numArea, count(*)AS Quantitat metges 
FROM hospital.metge 
GROUP BY numArea 
HAVING count(*)>1
WHERE numArea IS NOT NULL;
```

Por supuesto no funciona, pero asi a simple vista hay algun error de sintaxi? quiero decir entre FROM  GROUP BY  HAVING Y WHERE debe haber una coma?

Comment: Hola Carlos. Añade la explicacion oportuna sobre por qué no funciona. Los errores de sintaxis deberias saberlo si tienes errores en la consulta. Añade más informacion siguiendo [ask]. Un saludo

Comment: Gracias ,asi dices, no?

Comment: Si, pero explica por qué no funciona: [Te he votado negativamente porque sólo dices que no funciona.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2871/15855).

Comment: Ahi esta el problema, que tampoco entiendo porque no funciona, en la sentencia le indico numArea, count <---aqui para que me cuente este numero de area si se repetite. luego un GROUP By supongo que me agrupa los valores dentro de num area. Pero yo basicamente lo que quiero es que me sume si más de un medico esta en un grupo de area y que me muestre este dato en pantalla. No se si se entendera pero gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Pero añade la informacion de qué datos tienes, cual es el resultado esperado de la consulta, que resultado estas obteniendo ... Y explicalo en la pregunta. **no** en los comentarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te invito a refrescar tus conocimientos sobre la [Sintaxis de SELECT en MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)

Como se puede ver a primera vista, lo que tienes mal es la clausula `WHERE`, que debería estar antes de `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT numArea, count(*)AS Quantitat metges 
FROM hospital.metge 
WHERE numArea IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY numArea 
HAVING count(*)>1;
```

El segundo error de sintaxis que podrías tener es en el nombre asignado a la columna que hace el `count` al que has llamado `Quantitat metges`.

Tienes 2 opciones:

Incluir un guión bajo a `Quantitat metges`, quedando `Quantitat_metges`.

Incluir comillas al principio y final del nombre `"Quantitat metges"`

```
SELECT numArea, count(*)AS "Quantitat metges" 
FROM hospital.metge 
WHERE numArea IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY numArea 
HAVING count(*)>1;
```

Comment: Gracias Paco. Me queda por ver como funciona el count, voy a darle algunas vueltas mas y si no me sale pongo otro post con todo mejor explicado.